# visual issue with UITextField. Text past the length of the field doesnt show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

This might be kind of hard to explain in a way to easily understand.. but basically I am having an issue when first tapping into a text field.  When the user starts typing text, if the text reaches the end of the textfield, rather than the view scroll with the cursor as the user continues to type, the cursor just stops at the end of the textfield, but the field continues to register inputs.  if the user closes the keyboard, and re-enters the textfield then it actually works as it should, scrolling along with the new letters the user types beyond the length of the textfield.

Is this some strange setting I have on my text field? Is this a bug with iOS 8?  I don't even know where to begin to look to solve this issue.